# How do I share a csv file in an android app?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a file that I want to put in a send intent so the user can email the file, save it to Google Drive, etc. When I share it, the share sheet does display correctly. But if I choose Google Drive, the file just doesn't save, and trying to attach it to Gmail results in this error in a toast message:

```
Couldn't attach file.
```

The relevant code:

```
    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem) = when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.summaryExportBtn -> {
            try {
                val filename = "summary.csv"
                val summaryFile = File(cacheDir, filename)

                val fos = FileOutputStream(summaryFile)
                fos.write(getSummaryCsvString().toByteArray())
                fos.close()

                val summaryUri = getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", summaryFile)

                val sendIntent = Intent()
                sendIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, summaryUri)
                sendIntent.type = "text/csv"
                sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                sendIntent.data = summaryUri
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "SHARE"))
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d(FDSLogTag, "Writing csv summary failed: $e")
                val toast = Toast.makeText(this.applicationContext, "Writing csv summary failed: $e", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                toast.show()
            }

            true
        }

        else -> {
            super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
```

How do I successfully share the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure you have a file provider in the `<application>` section of your AndroidManifest.xml:

```xml
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

Then, create the provider_paths.xml file in app > res > xml folder:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <files-path name="summaries" path="summaries/" />
</paths>
```

Now you can create a file, write to it, and share it with the share intent:

```kotlin
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem) = when (item.itemId) {
    R.id.summaryExportBtn -> {
        try {
            val filename = "myfilename.csv"
            val myPath = File(filesDir, "mypath")
            if (!myPath.exists()) {
                myPath.mkdir()
            }
            val myFile = File(myPath, filename)

            // write the file here, e.g.
            FileOutputStream(myFile).use { stream ->
                stream.write(myCsvString.toByteArray())
            }

            // here, com.example.myapp.fileprovider should match the file provider in your manifest
            val contentUri = getUriForFile(this.applicationContext, "com.example.myapp.fileprovider", myFile)

            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
            intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
            intent.setDataAndType(
                    contentUri,
                    "text/csv")
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri);
            startActivity(intent)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d(FDSLogTag, "Writing csv failed: $e")
            val toast = Toast.makeText(this.applicationContext, "Writing csv failed: $e", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            toast.show()
        }

        true
    }

    else -> {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```